YOLOv11m Model Missing Objects at High Confidence Thresholds Compared to YOLOv7 – Need Help Optimizing Detection
I've recently upgraded my object detection project from YOLOv7 to YOLOv11m to take advantage of the newer model's capabilities. In YOLOv7, I achieved good detection accuracy with a confidence threshold of 0.7, and it performed well, detecting all relevant objects on my custom dataset.
Now, I trained the YOLOv11m model on the same dataset, using the pretrained weights (yolov11m.pt) and set the confidence threshold (conf) to 0.7 and the IoU threshold (iou_thresh) to 0.45. However, with YOLOv11m, many objects that were easily detected in YOLOv7 are now missed—even when I test on the training dataset.
Only when I reduce the confidence threshold to 0.3-0.4 does YOLOv11m begin to detect objects.
Why does YOLOv11m fail to detect objects at a high confidence threshold like 0.7, when YOLOv7 was able to do so without issues? Are there any adjustments or techniques I can use to improve YOLOv11m's detection performance at higher confidence levels?
Additional Details:

Dataset: Same dataset used in YOLOv7 and YOLOv11m training.

Model: YOLOv11m trained with yolov11m.pt pretrained weights.

Testing Configuration: conf = 0.7 (misses objects), iou_thresh = 0.45.

Current Solution: Lowering conf to 0.3-0.4, which allows detection but with more noise.


Any insights or optimization tips to make YOLOv11m detect more accurately at conf = 0.7 would be greatly appreciated!
